# Math equation in latex (varnothing)

Tags: equations

In a pseudocode, I would like to assign `\varnothing` to a variable.
My code goes like this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Find...} 
\begin{algorithmic}[1] \State $RS$ $\leftarrow$ $\varnothing$ \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The error message I got is the following:

> ```
> State $RS$ $\leftarrow \varnothing $ The control sequence at the end
> of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling
> (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about
> whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. 
> \varnothing l.103 ...\quad \quad $R$ $\leftarrow$ $\varnothing $
> \Comment{$R$ is the set ... The control sequence at the end of the top
> line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled
> it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,
> `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was
> undefined.
> ```

Do you have any ides on how this can be resolved?

FYI, I've already installed `amsmath` from `texlive-latex-base` in debian 9.

Thanks,
Pavlos

Comment: Could you add fully compilable `MWE`?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code fragment to complete small document (caled minimal working example: mwe) beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Find...}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $RS$ $\leftarrow$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}

Comment: @PavlosPonos You can also remove the comment with your code as Raaja has edited your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\varnothing` belongs to the set of symbols in the package `amssymb`. So include it in your preamble as `\usepackage{amssymb}` and you are good to go.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm} 
        \caption{Find...} 
        \begin{algorithmic}[1] \State $RS$ $\leftarrow$ $\varnothing$ \end{algorithmic} 
    \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

with which you will get:

[image]

Comment: \usepackage{amssymb} was the solution to my "problem". When adding this, without changing anything else, it solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Pavlos Ponos you are welcome.